# Instead of Trigger using dynamic sequences SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to auto generate `sequence_id` dynamically using sequences.

I have sequences `seq_C1`, `seq_C2`, `seq_C3`,.... like this. The next value of these sequences are provided below.

```
seq_C1: next value would be 121
seq_C2: next value would be 76
seq_C3: next value would be 2981
.....
.....
```

Sample data in the source_table:

```
ID  Name 
1   C1    
2   C1
3   C2
4   C2
5   C3
...
...
```

I have to auto increment `sequence_id` column based on the name column using sequence (dynamically).

The target table should be populated like this

```
ID  Name sequence_id
1   C1  121
2   C1  122
3   C2  76
4   C2  77
5   C3  2981
...
...
```

The target table is populated using select...insert statement using a stored procedure. There are around 100 to 1000 rows inserted to target using source table during single stored procedure call.

I created an instead of trigger to do this.

I tried the below SQL in the trigger but I got the error

> Invalid object name 'seq_'.

Code:

```
insert into target_table
    select 
        id, name, (NEXT VALUE FOR 'seq_' + NAME)
    from INSERTED
```

I am hitting my heads and struggling for the past two days. Kindly provide any suggestions to implement this. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward way to do this. `NEXT VALUE FOR` is expecting a *name*, not a *string*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Is any better way to achieve this.

Comment: It depends on what the specific *requirements* are - i.e. my first gut feeling is to use a single sequence/identity and then *compute* appropriate values during `SELECT` using a `ROW_NUMBER()` expression and appropriate offset values. Assuming no deletions from the table, the overall effect is *similar*. But without knowing the requirements, not sure if that would be sufficient.

Comment: These sequences are already created and utilized in the existing system. I have to make use of these sequences to populate the Sequence_IDs

Comment: @marc_s: Do you have any suggestions to do this.

Comment: Not sure if you could use a `CASE` to select from one or the other sequence - based on some criteria....

Comment: I have plenty of sequences so I don't want to use case here since in future there might be some additional sequences so I have to rewrite the code. I am looking for some dynamic approach

Comment: If you want to start using a *dynamic* approach - then you probably have to use dynamic SQL for the entire statement; I don't see how you can do it otherwise ..

Comment: Added to which, you'll have to start copying data around since in the dynamic scope, `inserted` won't be available.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is something like this:

```
insert into target_table
select id,name, NEXT VALUE FOR seq_C1 from INSERTED where name='C1'
union all
select id,name, NEXT VALUE FOR seq_C2 from INSERTED where name='C2'
union all
select id,name, NEXT VALUE FOR seq_C3 from INSERTED where name='C3'
```

And hope that adding new sequences is a rare thing.

Comment: I shared only three sequences but actually there are plenty of sequences in place